# excluding sub dir in command

Tags: files, command

I need to provide a detailed list of files in a directory in **descending** order of the **file size**. only to **include 10 files** in my output. I **can not include sub directories** in my output. I'm having the problem with the last part, "not including sub directories" here is what I have so far but I'm stuck on excluding subdirectories. Also if you could look at the below command to advise if this is correct

```
de@Classbox:~/LI_1/etc$ ls -lh -S | sort -r |head -10
```

I know if i use `grep -v d` it will exclude directories but I need it to exclude subdirectories.

Comment: Your `ls` command is not recursing subdirectories; if this is part of a class to learn `ls` and `grep`, perhaps they're looking for `ls ... | grep -v ^d`?  You'll likely get different answers here, so it'd be best to clearly explain where you're coming from and what you're expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't expect meaningful results if you sort by "human readable" file sizes. Try

```
ls -l| sort -k1,1.1 -k5nr | head -n 10
```

If there are less than 10 regular files, you need additional measures.

Comment: Hi this worked great for me. could you break down the sort command to what it means though so i can understand the command

Comment: The `-k` are key definitions. `-k1,1.1` sort on the line's first char, `-` first, `d` last, i.e. directories a retrailing. Then, within the file types, `-k5nr` sorts by size, numerically, reversely / descending.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `zsh` shell:

```
printf '%s\n' *(.OL[1,10])
```

The `(.OL[1,10])` is a *glob modifier* that modifies the behaviour of the preceding glob pattern (`*`).  In this case, the `.` means it will only match regular files (i.e. not directories, sockets, fifos etc.), `OL` means sorting in descending order (`O`) based on the file size/length (`L`). The `[1,10]` limits the number of returned matches to the first 10.

To include hidden files, set the `GLOB_DOTS` shell option with `setopt GLOB_DOTS`.